# Quartic Space Curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, ac.commutative-algebra

It is an exercise in Hartshorne to classify nonsingular quartic curves in projective 3-space. I am interested in what happens when we allow singularities. In particular, I am looking for an explanation or source for how to exclude the possibility of a space curve of arithmetic genus 1 and a single node or cusp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Singular nondegenerate irreducible degree $4$ curves certainly exist.  They can be obtained as complete intersections of two quadric surfaces which are tangent at some point.

Thinking differently, any curve of class $(2,2)$ on a nonsingular quadric $Q$ is a degree $4$ space curve.  The series $|\mathcal{O}_Q(2)|$ is $8$-dimensional, and the singular curves in this family form a $7$-dimensional subvariety.  Cuspidal members of this family form a smaller $6$-dimensional locus.

Answer (score 11):

Take a rational normal quartic  curve $C$  in ${\mathbb P}^4$ and  project it to ${\mathbb P}^3$ from a point $P\notin C$. The image $X$ of $C$  is a quartic. Moreover $X$ is smooth if $P$ is general, it has a node if $P$ lies on a secant line of $C$ and a cusp if $P$ lies on a tangent line to $C$. 
All rational irreducible non degenerate quartics in ${\mathbb P}^3$ arise in this way.